# How do Ingress Controller and Ingress work together?

Tags: kubernetes

I don't see any link between the service and Ingress yaml files. How is it linked and how does it work? I looked at the nginx ingress controller but couldn't find any links to the ingress either.

How does the traffic flow? `LB -> Ingress controller -> Ingress -> Backend service -> pods`? And it seems only 80 and 443 are allowed by ingress. Does that mean any custom ports defined on `ingress-nginx service` is directly connected to the pod through like `LB -> Backend service -> Pod`?

Update: Figured out the traffic flow. Its as follows:
`LB -> Ingress controller -> Ingress -> Backend service -> pods`

I have a `https virtual host with a custom port` and I guess I need to edit the `ingress-controller` yaml file to allow custom port and add the custom port to ingress and would it start routing?

`Ingress.yml:`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: test
  rules:
    - path: /
      backend:
        serviceName: httpd
        servicePort: 443
```

`cloud-generic-service.yml:`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
data:
  1234: "test-web-dev/httpd:1234"
  1235: "test-web-dev/tomcat7:1235"
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
    - name: https
      port: 443
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: https
    - name: port-1234
      port: 1234
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 1234
    - name: port-1235
      port: 1235
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 1235
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation to this can be found [in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress)

> Ingress exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to
> services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules
> defined on the Ingress resource.
>
> An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable
> URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name-based
> virtual hosting.

So `Ingress` routes traffic from outside the cluster to service that you've specified in it, `httpd` in your example. You can specify how traffic should be used by [adding annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/) (example of annotation for nginx ingress).

> The Ingress controller is an application that runs in a cluster and
> configures an HTTP load balancer according to Ingress resources. The
> load balancer can be a software load balancer running in the cluster
> or a hardware or cloud load balancer running externally. Different
> load balancers require different Ingress controller implementations.

> In the case of NGINX, the Ingress controller is deployed in a pod along with the > load balancer.

`Ingress` resources requires [`Ingress controller`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/how-it-works/#how-it-works) to be present in the cluster. It is not deployed in to the cluster by default that's why it has has to be installed manually.

Comment: Can you tell me about the traffic flow? `LB -> Ingress controller -> Ingress` ? or `LB -> Ingress -> Ingress Controller`? And it seems only 80 and 443 are allowed by ingress. Any custom ports on `ingress-nginx` service is directly connected to the pod through node port?

Comment: I've updated the `ingress-nginx` to show custom ports that I've defined

Comment: You check https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/tcp-udp and let me know if that's what you are looking for.